# Error in scipy Wilcoxon signed-rank test

Tags: statistics, scipy

I was digging in the scipy code for this test Wilcoxon signed-rank test ([`stats.wilcoxon`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wilcoxon.html)) and I found that in scipy they compute the sum of the ranks for the differences that are positives and separately for the ones that are negatives. Then they picked the smaller one and use that as W.
That is substantially different from the test explanation in Wikipedia, or other sites(http://vassarstats.net/textbook/ch12a.html) where W = sum(all the differences).

Is this approach valid?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Is there a question in here? You noticing a difference between two sources; what would you like the community to help you with? Unfortunately, this is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) in its current form. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I would like to know if the scipy implementation is wrong from the statistical point of view. Thanks for the help

Comment: FYI: While there have been tweaks to the code over the years, the computation implemented in `wilcoxon` goes back to this commit from 2002: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/11c47a7b3d9be67a68dc30a754538e7a6c44ace0

Comment: There was an addition of options to the way ties/zeros are handled recently https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/1f88b1c74a09b840678438103760bf7652cb871a  and the results are the same as in R. My guess is that you have different expressions for the same result in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many statistical functions, there are alternate definitions which have different properties. Sometimes one is more useful, sometimes another. To find out why the author or authors of scipy chose the definition you found, you'll have to ask them. My advice is to look at the revision history (Git or whatever, I don't know what Scipy uses) of scipy.Wilcoxon or ask on the Scipy developers mailing list. Hope this helps.